# Problem to Flash Chinesse Tablet MT6580

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, flashtool

I have problems flashing the firmware of a tablet with **Mt6580**, I am using SP flash tools and Betools.

The problem is that the flashing runs normally and ends without problems, but the tablet does not turn on. When reading the Region `EMMC_USER` with The SP flash tool, it is empty. However, the `EMMC_BOOT` region is the only one that is written and is where the `preloader.bin` is loaded, but the rest of the files are not written.

What could it be that the `EMMC_USER` region is not written?